# Преобразование координат

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Есть код:

```
///Предоставляет простые преобразования.
unit Transform;
{$gendoc true}

type
  ///Тип точки.
  TPoint = record
    X, Y: real;

    ///Вернуть строку, представляющую точку.
    function ToString()  := Format('Transform.TPoint: X = {0}, Y = {1}', X, Y);
  end;

  ///Тип отступа.
  TMargin = record
    MarginLeftX, MarginDownY: integer;
    MarginRightX, MarginUpY: integer;

    ///Вернуть строку, представляющую отступ.
    function ToString()  := Format('Transform.TMargin: MarginLeftX = {0}, MarginDownY = {1}, MarginRightX = {2}, MarginUpY = {3}', MarginLeftX, MarginDownY, MarginRightX, MarginUpY);
  end;

  ///Тип окна.
  TWindow = record
    Width, Height: integer;

    ///Вернуть строку, представляющую окно.
    function ToString()  := Format('Transform.TWindow: Width = {0}, Height = {1}', Width, Height);
  end;

///Возвращает точку в оконных координатах.
function ToWindowCoordinates(p: TPoint; w: TWindow): TPoint;
begin
  Result.X := 0.5 * (p.X + 1) * w.Width;
  Result.Y := -0.5 * (p.Y - 1) * w.Height;
end;

///Возвращает точку в оконных координатах.
function ToWindowCoordinates(p: TPoint; m: TMargin; w: TWindow): TPoint;
begin
  Result.X := m.MarginLeftX + 0.5 * (p.X + 1) * (w.Width - m.MarginLeftX - m.MarginRightX);
  Result.Y := m.MarginDownY - 0.5 * (p.Y - 1) * (w.Height - m.MarginDownY - m.MarginUpY);
end;

///Возвращает точку в логических координатах.
function ToLogicalCoordinates(p: TPoint; w: TWindow): TPoint; // Здесь проблема.
begin
  Result.X := 2 * p.X / w.Width - 1;
  Result.Y := 2 * p.Y / w.Height + 1;
end;

///Возвращает точку в логических координатах.
function ToLogicalCoordinates(p: TPoint; m: TMargin; w: TWindow): TPoint; // Здесь проблема.
begin
  //  Result.X := m.MarginLeftX + 0.5 * (p.X + 1) * (w.Width - m.MarginLeftX - m.MarginRightX);
  //  0.5 * (p.X + 1) * (w.Width - m.MarginLeftX - m.MarginRightX) = Result.X - m.MarginLeftX
  //  p.X + 1 = 2 * (Result.X - m.MarginLeftX) / (w.Width - m.MarginLeftX - m.MarginRightX)
  //  p.X = 2 * (Result.X - m.MarginLeftX) / (w.Width - m.MarginLeftX - m.MarginRightX) - 1
  //
  //  Result.Y := m.MarginDownY - 0.5 * (p.Y - 1) * (w.Height - m.MarginDownY - m.MarginUpY);
  //  0.5 * (p.Y - 1) * (w.Height - m.MarginDownY - m.MarginUpY) = Result.Y - m.MarginDownY
  //  p.Y - 1 = 2 * (Result.Y - m.MarginDownY) / (w.Height - m.MarginDownY - m.MarginUpY)
  //  p.Y = 2 * (Result.Y - m.MarginDownY) / (w.Height - m.MarginDownY - m.MarginUpY) + 1
  //
  Result.X := 2 * (p.X - m.MarginLeftX) / (w.Width - m.MarginLeftX - m.MarginRightX) - 1;
  Result.Y := 2 * (p.Y - m.MarginDownY) / (w.Height - m.MarginDownY - m.MarginUpY) + 1;
end;
end.
```

Программа для тестирования:

```
uses GraphABC, Transform;
var
  P: TPoint;
  W: TWindow;

begin
  P.X := 0.5;
  P.Y := 0.5;
  W.Width := Window.Width;
  W.Height := Window.Height;

  var P2 := ToWindowCoordinates(P, W);
  Writeln(P2.ToString());
  var P3 := ToLogicalCoordinates(P2, W);
  Writeln(P3.ToString());

  DrawCircle(Round(P2.X), Round(P2.Y), 10);
end.
```

Но почему координаты P и P3 различные?

Comment: а должны быть одинаковые?

Comment: Да. Я же преобразую так: логические -> оконные -> логические. Нужно чисто для проверки правильности работы обратного преобразования из оконных в логические координаты.

Comment: может быть Вы имеете в виду равенство `P` и `P3`?

Comment: Да, именно это и имею ввиду. Перепутал, сорян.

Comment: "P2 и P3 различные" - какие именно - это мы должны угадать?

Comment: Проблема с координатой Y пока что.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71084/discussion-between-vladislav-moldovan-and-igor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минус забыли:

```
function ToLogicalCoordinates(p: TPoint; w: TWindow): TPoint;
begin
  Result.X := 2 * p.X / w.Width - 1;
  Result.Y := -2 * p.Y / w.Height + 1;
end;
```